# WSOD after migrating to another site? Troubleshooting a site migration

Tags: 6, migrations, wsod

I'm in the process of migrating from one URL to another, and I've got a WSOD. What I had done is to import the new database from the production server.

- I've copied all the files from another server using SCP;
- I've then SCPed the database from the other server;
- I have imported the database from command line;
- I have changed the settings.php to the correct information.

I have the feeling it's something simple that I haven't ruled out.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember to check the PHP version. It's running on PHP 4.

Comment: =) Vote up as it easy to forget details!

Comment: You should explain how the PHP version is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Because Drupal cannot run on php 4.

Comment: Your question is tagged Drupal 6, which can run on PHP 4 (4.4 at any rate); it was only Drupal 7 that introduced the requirement for PHP 5.2.6.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at Apache error.log which generally contains information regarding the error.
Also the Drupal handbook have great tips to debug this error, see: http://drupal.org/node/158043